# Deployed flex applet not processing web service results

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

When I test my deployed app in a browser the popup window continues to be displayed even after it should be closed. Everything works as expected when debugged in Flash Builder 4.

Following is currently what's happening: the request is sent to my restful web service, which processes the request, (seemingly) the `ResultEvent` is called which in turn dispatches the `profileEvt` dynamic event that changes the view state. However, the popup window does not get closed and the applet gets 'stuck.'

Anyone know what could be the problem? Below are the flex applet web service event listeners/handlers:

```
webService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, function(event:ResultEvent):void 
                    {
                        var rawData:String = String(event.result);
                        var profileEvt:DynamicEvent = new DynamicEvent("profileSaved", true);
                        profileEvt.data = JSON.decode(rawData).profile;
                        dispatchEvent(profileEvt); // Dispatch profile saved event
                        _progressPopUp.closePopUp();
                        dispatchEvent(event); // Dispatch submit profile button clicked
                    });
webService.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, function(event:FaultEvent):void 
                    {
                        Alert.show("Could not create profile; please try again later.\n" + event.message, "Status");
                        _progressPopUp.closePopUp();
                    });
                    var params:Object = {"profile" : profile};
try
                    {
                        _progressPopUp = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, com.profs.ui.components.ProgressPopUp, true);
                        _progressPopUp.eventSource = webService; // Set source of progress events
                        webService.send(JSON.encode(params));   
                    }
```

**NOTE:**
`com.profs.ui.components.ProgressPopUp` is a custom component; the code for it is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" layout="absolute" width="300" height="200" showCloseButton="false" title="Status" creationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Declarations></fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            [Bindable] public var eventSource:Object;

            private function init():void 
            {
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(this);
            }
            public function closePopUp():void 
            {
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(this); 
            }
            public function completionHandler(event:Event):void 
            {
                closePopUp();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:ProgressBar id="progressBar" indeterminate="true" mode="event" source="{eventSource}" complete="completionHandler(event)" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0"/>
</mx:TitleWindow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the `com.profs.ui.components.progressPopUp` component, but it is possible that the `closePopUp()` method has a bug in it. You could try to remove the `ProgressPopUp` directly using the `PopUpManager` method. For example instead of:

```
_progressPopUp.closePopUp();
```

try

```
PopUpManager.removePopUp(_progressPopUp);
```

I also don't know off the top of my head what the rules for closures are (i.e. at which point is the `_progressPopUp` variable copied into the `ResultEvent.RESULT` event handler. You could try moving that particular event handler below the line where you actually created the `_progressPopUp` instance.